# Gzipping css files in Rollup

Tags: css, sass, gzip, rollup

I am trying to bundle my js and scss files in rollup ready for production.
Rollup takes all of my files and outputs them to a build dir, the result looks like this:

```
build
  css
    bundle.css
  js
    bundle.js
    bundle.js.gz
```

As you can see, I am using the `gzipPlugin` for my js files.
I also want to use `gzipPlugin` to handle my css, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

My current setup looks like this:

```
import babel from "rollup-plugin-babel";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import multi from "@rollup/plugin-multi-entry";
import gzipPlugin from "rollup-plugin-gzip"
import scss from "rollup-plugin-scss"
import del from "rollup-plugin-delete"

export default [{
    input: "src/**/*.logic.js",
    output: {
        file: "build/assets/js/main.min.js",
        format: "umd",
        name: "Logic"
    },
    plugins: [
        del({ targets: "build" }),
        gzipPlugin(),
        terser({
            output: {
                wrap_iife: false
            }
        }),
        multi({
            exports: true
        }),
        babel({
            exclude: "node_modules/**"
        })
    ]
}, {
    input: "src/all.scss",
    plugins: [
        scss({
            output: "build/assets/css/styles.min.css",
            outputStyle: "compressed"
        }),
    ]
}
];
```

My question is:
**How can I get my outputted css file to be gzipped?**.

I think I am missing something fairly simply, I just can't see how to get gzipPlugin working on the css file.... thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to add the gzipPlugin in the plugins session of your CSS generation.

Like this:

```
input: "src/all.scss",
plugins: [
    scss({
        output: "build/assets/css/styles.min.css",
        outputStyle: "compressed"
    }),
    gzipPlugin()
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by specifying the `additionalFiles` option:

```
// rollup.config.js
...
import gzipPlugin from "rollup-plugin-gzip";
import css from "rollup-plugin-css-only";

export default {
  input: "src/main.js",
  output: {
    ...
    file: "public/build/bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    gzipPlugin({
      additionalFiles: ["./public/build/bundle.css"],
    }),
    css({ output: "bundle.css" }),
    ...
  ]
}
```

One little quirk I ran into was that the build has to be run twice. The first time without gzip to generate the `bundle.css` and the second time to gzip the `bundle.css` from the previous run.